# Function returning a recordset

Tags: excel, vba

I have wrote 2 functions, in one function I am creating a sql statement and sending it to another function where I run the query and return the record set.

The problem is that when I return the record set and try to set it, it's not working.

```
Function DB_Exp(ByVal sht, range_IDent)

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.EnableEvents = False
MoveCursor = False


Dim MyData As String, strData() As String, TmpAr() As String
Dim TwoDArray() As String
Dim i As Long, n As Long
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

FilePath = Sheets("dbs").Cells(12, "J") & "Log.csv"

Open FilePath For Binary As #1
MyData = Space$(LOF(1))
Get #1, , MyData
Close #1
strData() = Split(MyData, vbCrLf)

For i = LBound(strData) To UBound(strData)
If Len(Trim(strData(i))) <> 0 Then
    TmpAr = Split(strData(i), Delim)
    num_str = UBound(TmpAr, 1)
    countString = "Select count(*) from [Checking].[dbo].[Data]"

    Set rs = ADOExcelSQLServer(countString)

    Debug.Print rs.RecordCount 'Getting Error Here

    If rs.EOF And rs.BOF Then
    Else
        Do While Not rs.EOF
            For j = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
                Debug.Print rs.Fields(j).Value
            Next j
            rs.MoveNext
        Loop
    End If
    n = n + 1
    ReDim Preserve TwoDArray(1, 1 To n)
    '~~> TmpAr(1) : 1 for Col B, 0 would be A
    TwoDArray(1, n) = TmpAr(2)
End If
Next i
End Function
```

```
Function ADOExcelSQLServer(sStr) As ADODB.Recordset

Dim Cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim Server_Name As String
Dim Database_Name As String
Dim User_ID As String
Dim Password As String
Dim SQLStr As String
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

Server_Name = "" ' Enter your server name here
Database_Name = "" ' Enter your database name here
User_ID = "" ' enter your user ID here
Password = "" ' Enter your password here

Set Cn = New ADODB.Connection
Cn.Open "Driver={SQL Server};Server=" & Server_Name & ";Database=" & Database_Name & _
";Uid=" & User_ID & ";Pwd=" & Password & ";"
rs.Open sStr, Cn, adOpenStatic

If rs.EOF And rs.BOF Then
    Set ADOExcelSQLServer = Null
Else
    Set ADOExcelSQLServer = rs
End If

Cn.Close
Set Cn = Nothing
End Function
```

I am getting an error at Debug.Print rs.RecordCount 'Getting Error Here

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Operation is not allowed when object is closed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error occurs because you are closing the connection object in the function, effectively also closing open recordsets even if it follows the function return line. Simply remove the `Cn.Close` line.

```
If rs.EOF And rs.BOF Then
    Set ADOExcelSQLServer = Null
Else
    Set ADOExcelSQLServer = rs
End If

'Cn.Close                                <---- REMOVE 
Set Cn = Nothing
```

Comment: this has resolved my issue but now I am not able to extract data from rs can you please tell me how can I get data out of this record set ?

I have tried to print  `rs.RecordCount` that gives me output 1.

But when I try to print `rs.fields(j).Value` as per my code above it gives an error "Either BOF or EOF is true, or the current record has been deleted"

Comment: I am surprised when I run through Record Set in Function ADOExcelSQLServer, by using  `rs.fields(j).Value` it works fine. But when I pass record set to DB_Exp and do the same thing it gives me an error

Comment: I know I tested above with my data and not specifically your code and did not receive any error. Admittedly, I did not use arrays or loops. Will check your code. And some recordsets are not forward-looking so cannot give accurate record count

Comment: its been fixed the problem was I was looping through the record set and moving the pointer to next record set and when I try again in the other function to print record set the pointer was already at the end so it gives error. I used `rs.MoveFirst` and it worked. :) thanks for your help